# Custom special abilities rules

Tags: arkham-horror, balance

I know ther are some rules for creating custom Investigators, so new character is balanced and does not ruin the game. It's utilized in Strange Eons.

Are there any rules for custom special abilities for Investigators?

I am creating custom Investigator, who is psychologist like Carolyn Fern, but I don't like to copy her ability. Instead, I thought about ability to restore Sanity in exchange for Clue tokens in 1-to-1 basis during upkeep. Player would be able to use as much Clue tokens as he/she likes and restore Sanity to himself/herself or players in the same area.

I would like to know if there are any rules to check if given special is not over/underpowered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that would really be up to your own experience that you want to have when playing the game.  Also, doing some play testing would be beneficial in getting a good understanding of whether or not it is over/underpowered.  I know it is a long game, but I would think after one game you would know more of what needs to be tweaked to determine the power of that ability.  And you could always offset that ability by providing lower stats, possessions, and etc.